# Where to set CakePHP 3 cookie config

Tags: cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.1

I want to set the config for the cookie component but I am unsure where to add the code.

Do I set it in the AppController or the bootstrap?

```
public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();

    $this->loadComponent('Csrf');

    $this->Cookie->config([
        'httpOnly' => true
    ]);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components.html#configuring-components

> Some examples of components requiring configuration are Authentication and Cookie. Configuration for these components, and for components in general, is usually done via loadComponent() in your Controller’s initialize() method or via the $components array.

Assuming that you need to configure it globally, you should place the configurationcode into the `initialize()` of the `AppController`.

If you want to override the configuration at runtime, you can place the code into the `beforeFilter()` of a controller.

Comment: I did try the `initialize()` in the `AppController` but I get a Fatal Error - `Error: Call to a member function config() on a non-object`

Comment: have you loaded the component using `$this->loadComponent('Cookie');`?

Comment: Yes thank you. After reading the supplied link to the doc I noticed my error and I had just implemented the correction `$this->loadComponent('Cookie', ['httpOnly' => true]);`